# Latest compatible versions of Nutch and Solr

Tags: solr, nutch

I see different combinations of Nutch and Solr versions being used by people posting about this subject on the web.
Which are the latest stable (non beta) and compatible versions of Nutch and Solr that I can download and setup without building sources and just configuring ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use Nutch 2.1 or Nutch 1.6. If you want to use HBase, have to use Nutch 2.x. Because nutch 1.6 not support Hbase. I use nutch 2.1, HBase 0.90.x or 0.94.5 , and Solr 4.3.0.

There are major changes between the two Solr versions (Solr 3.x and Solr 4.x). You must choose one of them according to your requirement. Ex: Solr4 support `cloud` better.

Answer (score 3):

Here are some suggested compatible versions of Nutch and Solr based on what the Nutch's creators are announcing in their website [here](http://nutch.apache.org/):

```
+-------+--------+
| Nutch |  Solr  |
+-------+--------+
| 2.3.1 | 4.10.3 |
|   2.3 |  4.8.1 |
+-------+--------+
```

Feel free to add more versions. The tool I used to generate this table can be found [here](https://ozh.github.io/ascii-tables/).

Answer (score 2):

What OS are you using?

In Windows Nutch 1.2 was the latest version I managed to get working.

In Linux Nutch 1.6 works very well with SOLR.

That was in combination with SOLR 3.5 (because of other dependencies) but there's no reason for it not to work with SOLR 3.6 or 4.3.

[Nutch tutorial](http://wiki.apache.org/nutch/NutchTutorial)

Comment: I'm using Ubuntu Server 12.04 LTS.
I just tried SOLR 4.3.0 and Nutch 1.6.

Both are working (Solr running in Tomcat and Nutch successfully crawled a small site).

When I tried running the Nutch solrindex command to integrate them and index the crawled site with solr, I got a java.io.IOException Job failed!   error. No further detail in solr or nutch logs.

I'm wondering if this can be due to incompatibilities between the two versions...

Comment: The hadoop.log file usually has more details. Can you post the stack trace of the error? If there are no more details, try changing the conf/log4j.properties and change the debug levels from INFO to DEBUG

Comment: in the meantime i followed a different process: I started Solr using Jetty instead of Tomcat. Seems that when the Nutch tutorial tells you to copy the schema file from Nutch to Solr is not enough. Also the schema file under /collection1/conf has to be edited. I had to add the 5 field definitions for segment, boost, digest, tstamp, anchor. Now also the integration step works fine and the content has been indexed by Solr. One last thing: relative URLs where not considered and I had to add +^/  to /nutch/conf/domain-urlfilter.txt

Answer (score 2):

I implemented Nutch 1.6 and Solr 3.6.2 into a production system earlier this year for a large financial firm. They work very well together.

Comment: did you use Tomcat or Jetty for Solr ?

Comment: I have used both, and in both cases they are proxied via Apache.

Comment: Hi Claude. Have you ever tried Nutch 2.2.1 with HBase into a production system?

Comment: No, although I tested version 2.x and found that it was not as stable as 1.6. The older more stable version provided all the features we sought to implement in that project.

Answer (score 0):

I am using -

- Apache Nutch 2.3.1
- Solr 5.2.1
- HBase 0.94.14

And these combination is working fine!