# How to use Apache Nutch through a Java application?

Tags: java, nutch

I have to design a Java/Java EE based search engine using apache nutch. I have searched over the internet and I found many articles regarding installation of apache nutch but unable to find any article/tutorial which deals with the java program to access or control apache nutch for crawling.

Comment: You may see the example in my GitHub repository: https://github.com/yegor256/nutch-in-java Here I use Nutch without the command line, straight from the Java app.

Comment: You can use the [REST API](https://wiki.apache.org/nutch/NutchRESTAPI) to control Apache Nutch.

Answer (score 1):

Apache Nutch is only going to help you crawl for data, but you need to index what it finds into a search server. This is where Apache Solr comes in. Then you can write your Java application to interact with Solr using [SolrJ](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/Solrj).

See [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16571463/latest-compatible-versions-of-nutch-and-solr) for what versions of Nutch and Solr work best together.

Comment: I have successfully crawled a website using Nutch 2.1 and persisted data in a Mysql database using a command from terminal.               I have to write a program for controlling nutch so that i can add a list of urls to seed.txt and regex-filter file and execute a function in java program to crawl a list of urls.

Comment: Hi Abhijeet. I am also working on the same kind of issue. Can you please help me?

Answer (score -3):

Nutch will be your backend to do crawling. Then you will use solr indexing and then your front end will search on this solr index. See this link here http://www.building-blocks.com/thinking/building-a-search-engine-with-nutch-and-solr-in-10-minutes

Comment: If I am using Nutch to crawl and MySQL to store data...how am i going to fetch data from MySQL?

Comment: Its not clear to me. Once you have data in MySQL , what is the issue in fetching it. MySql and java are very easy to use together.

Comment: I was talking about how to fetch data from Mysql a d display on JSP page

Comment: This is pretty standard. There are many tutorials available for this. http://www.9lessons.info/2008/09/jsp-login-page-to-connect-mysql-atabase.html

Comment: ..It will be great if you can find some time to chat..i need some guidelines and it seems that you have a good knowledge of nutch based applications. Is it possible to chat..this wont take much time...

Comment: sure may be on this monday we can have a chat.

Comment: I really appreciate !!my gmail id is abhijeetkunwar@gmail.com ...please email me your gtalk id or skype id or just your emailid so that i can send you mine. Thanks and regards.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/32129/discussion-between-abhijeet-and-abhinav)