# Nutch - Which version to use for Apache Solr

Tags: solr, nutch

I understand that `Nutch 1.x` is based on Hadoop (map and reduce), and that `Nutch 2.x` can be used on NoSQL `Apache Gora`.

But which version is the best to use with Apache Solr ? or will it depend on the website crawled size ?

Comment: Similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16571463/latest-compatible-versions-of-nutch-and-solr

Comment: okey! how do I resolve it?